# How to select all checkboxes, while clicking the main checkbox in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox

**I need selecting the main checkbox, the all other partial checkboxes also selected**

My Requirement is ,I have a checkbox selectAll and some other checkboxes,by clicking this selectAll checkbox ,all other checkboxes must selected.And while clicking the partial checkbox the selectAll checkbox selection must gone.

```
 selectAllCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                isPartial = true;
                splitItemAdapter.selectAllItem(cb.isChecked());
                if (isFromCashPayment) {
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                      selectAllCheckbox.setChecked(true);
                      isitemChecked = true;




                    } else {

                        selectAllCheckbox.setChecked(false);

                        isitemChecked = false;



                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: once I clicking all the partial checkbox, I have no selection in the main checkbox.

Comment: you have to add setOnClickListener on partial checkbox too, and loop through   all check box and update selectAllCheckbox.

Comment: if (cb.isChecked()){selectAllCheckbox.setChecked(true)} is redundant. cb IS selectAllCheckbox

Comment: I hope you got the answer. :)

Comment: Hello mam, I have answered as per the question asked and it is working perfectly from my side. If you face any issue in that, kindly let me know. If you found this perfect kindly upvote and accept for getting a better idea for the readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way. Firstly, all checkbox to be in one layout. And then you use this code block.

layout.xml

```
...
 <CheckBox android:id="@+id/allCheckbox" />
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/checkboxLayouts"...>

               <CheckBox  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

               <CheckBox  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

               <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

               <CheckBox  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
...
```

Code

```
LinearLayout checkboxLayout = findViewById(R.id.checkboxLayouts);

checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
       for(int i=0 ; i < checkboxLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
          if(checkboxLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox) {
             ((CheckBox) checkboxLayout.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(isChecked);
          }
       }
 }
});
```

Note: I can't check code. Sorry for syntax error.

Comment: This is not my requirement.I have  a main checkbox and several partial checkboxes.By clicking the all partial chechboxes ,the main checkbox also selected automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

OnCreate

```
        parent = findViewById(R.id.parent_checkbox);
        child1 = findViewById(R.id.child_checkbox_1);
        child2 = findViewById(R.id.child_checkbox_2);

        parent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        child1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        child2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

OnCheckChanged

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        checkCheckBox(buttonView);
    }
```

checkCheckBox Method

```
public void checkCheckBox(View view){
     if (parent.isChecked() && view.getId() == R.id.parent_checkbox){
         child1.setChecked(true);
         child2.setChecked(true);
     }
     else if (!parent.isChecked() && view.getId() == R.id.parent_checkbox){
         if (child1.isChecked() && child2.isChecked()){
             child1.setChecked(false);
             child2.setChecked(false);
         }
     }
     else if (!parent.isChecked()){
         if (child1.isChecked() && child2.isChecked()){
             parent.setChecked(true);
         }
     }
     else if (parent.isChecked() && !child1.isChecked() || !child2.isChecked()){
         parent.setChecked(false);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the logic with this demo kotlin code...

```
        checkBox1.setOnClickListener {
            if (checkBox2.isChecked) {
                selectAllCheckbox.isChecked = true
            }

            if (!checkBox2.isChecked || !checkBox1.isChecked) {
                selectAllCheckbox.isChecked = false
            }
        }
        checkBox2.setOnClickListener {
            if (checkBox1.isChecked) {
                selectAllCheckbox.isChecked = true
            }
            if (!checkBox1.isChecked || !checkBox2.isChecked) {
                selectAllCheckbox.isChecked = false
            }
        }
        selectAllCheckbox.setOnClickListener {
            if (selectAllCheckbox.isChecked) {
                checkBox1.isChecked = true
                checkBox2.isChecked = true
            }
            if (!selectAllCheckbox.isChecked) {
                checkBox1.isChecked = false
                checkBox2.isChecked = false
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of Select All Checkboxes function is as below, the code is simpler in Kotlin language:

```
private val checkboxes by lazy {
    listOf(
        checkbox1,
        checkbox2,
        checkbox3,
        checkboxX
    )
}

// can implement the CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener on an Activity or Fragment instead
private val onCheckedChangeListener = CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { button, isChecked ->
    if (!buttonView.isPressed)
        // note that this breaks when accessibility mode is enabled,
        // e.g. isPressed() returns false e.g. when the event is triggered by a double tap from voice assistant.
        return

    when(buttonView.id) {
        R.id.checkboxSelectAll -> {
            checkboxes.forEach { it.isChecked = isChecked }
        }
        else -> {
            if (isChecked && checkboxes.all { it.isChecked }) {
                checkboxSelectAll.isChecked = true
            } else if (!isChecked && checkboxSelectAll.isChecked) {
                checkboxSelectAll.isChecked = false
            }
        }
    }
}

// assume this code is within an Activity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity)

    checkboxSelectAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
    checkboxes.forEach { it.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener) }
}
```

*Note that this solution is not working for apps that are required to support accessibility.